# Python library to scrape formatted text from arbitrary webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, computer-vision

I'm doing a project in Python which involves:

1. Extracting source code from webpage in url given as input (using Selenium with Chrome WebDriver)
2. Parse the source code and extract the visible text (using BeautifulSoup)
3. Do Natural Language Processing (NLP) on the extracted text

Although, for the NLP to be successful, the text needs to be extracted as it is visually presented in the browser - which doesn't always coincide with the formatting on the source code, i.e. sometimes the text from a paragraph is broken down into several different elements -> which breaks the scraping all together and makes it non-viable for NLP.

I know it's a really challenging task to develop such "visual based" scraper, as opposed to a "element based" one, but is there something already developed on that direction?

Comment: Can we test it?

Comment: This is an issue I've frequently run into myself and to my knowledge there isn't really a library-based solution like you're suggesting.  It usually comes down to "how arbitrary is arbitrary" - i.e., are there 3-5 formats that repeat overwhelmingly, and the arbitrariness is just in the order of them? That's more manageable than, for example, being able to reliably scrape any arbitrary forum post w/ formatting intact.

Answer (score 0):

Once I found this snippet somewhere in SO for one of my projects. It can give you the visible text as if the whole text were in one element, although they weren't. You just need to pass the parent element. Could also be `body` element. If you are using JS for scraping, just apply the JS script.

```
def get_visible_text(self, el):
        '''
        Get visible text in a given element
        '''

        get_text_script = '''
            function getVisibleText(element) {
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                let range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNode(element);
                window.getSelection().addRange(range);
                let visibleText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                return visibleText;
            }
            return getVisibleText(arguments[0]);
        '''

        return self.driver.execute_script(get_text_script, el)
```

Note: Sorry, I couldn't comment due to low reputation points.